# Compaq Visual Fortran 6.6, Dynamic-Link Library (DLL) and Module

Tags: dll, module, fortran, fortran90

I need to create and use dynamic-link library (DLL) for Fortran application using Compaq Visual Fortran 6.6. The following code works just fine:

```
PROGRAM AMAIN1
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL(8):: A,B,S
A = 1D0
B = 2D0
CALL SUBRO1(A,B,S)
PRINT*, 'S = ', S
END PROGRAM AMAIN1

SUBROUTINE SUBRO1(A,B,S)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: SUBRO1
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL(8):: A,B,S
S = A + B
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE SUBRO1
```

The result is correct:
S =    3.00000000000000
Press any key to continue

However, if I implement the same algorithm using the module, I get inconsistent result (i.e. zero):

```
PROGRAM AMAIN2
USE MODUL2
A = 1D0
B = 2D0
CALL SUBRO2
PRINT*, 'S = ', S
END PROGRAM AMAIN2

MODULE MODUL2
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL(8):: A,B,S
END MODULE MODUL2

SUBROUTINE SUBRO2
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: SUBRO2
USE MODUL2
S = A + B
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE SUBRO2
```

The result is incorrect:
S =   0.000000000000000E+000
Press any key to continue

As can be seen above, DLL contains only subprogram in both cases (SUBRO1 and SUBRO2, respectively). I have built DLL and LIB files from the visual development environment. The second case (with the use of module) represents the structure of my large source-code so I need to resolve this issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

BTW, the same algorithm without using the DLL works well and gives correct result:

```
PROGRAM AMAIN3
USE MODUL3
A = 1D0
B = 2D0
CALL SUBRO3
PRINT*, 'S = ', S
END PROGRAM AMAIN3

MODULE MODUL3
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL(8):: A,B,S
END MODULE MODUL3

SUBROUTINE SUBRO3
USE MODUL3
S = A + B
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE SUBRO3
```

The result is correct:
S =    3.00000000000000
Press any key to continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

`!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: A,B,S`

to the module, so that the main program can see the module variables from the DLL. Otherwise A, B and S are local variables.

Edit: January 16, 2019

I was able to log in to Bakhbergen's PC and eventually figured out the problem.

In CVF 6.6C (and the later Intel compilers), when you USE a module that has a DLLEXPORT directive, that turns into a DLLIMPORT, hence my advice above. But it wasn't always this way, and the version he has doesn't have that behavior. Before that change (which my memory says I lobbied for), you had to supply a separately compiled .mod where the source had DLLIMPORT instead of DLLEXPORT. When I did this, the program worked. I don't remember exactly which update had this change.

So what he needs to do is have two versions of MODUL2.f90, one with DLLEXPORT and one with DLLIMPORT. The DLLEXPORT version gets built into the DLL. The DLLIMPORT version would just be compiled (/c) and only the .mod used, not the ,obj, when linking the main program. Messy, I know, which is why we changed it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, Dr. Lionel, but it's not working. I hope I understood you and implemented it correctly. Have you run this on CVF 6.6?

Comment: No, but I did run it on Intel Fortran 19.0.1. CVF 6.6 is more than 15 years old and I no longer have a copy. I would have expected it to work, though, as when I was a CVF developer this was something I tried multiple times.

You need to add that line after:
`REAL(8):: A,B,S`
then rebuild both the DLL and the main program.

P.S. I am not a real doctor, I only play one on the web.

Comment: I hope I did everything that you wrote correctly, but still I am getting zero. :-) Thank you for your time and trying to help me. I see you are helping many people so for me you are just more than a doctor. Just in case, please let me know if you get a chance to run this code in CVF.

Comment: I no longer have access to CVF. I suggest posting your question at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows - I think there are still some CVF users there.

Comment: See my revised answer.